(GraphQL) Есть ли какие то проблемы использования Apollo на клиенте и AWS Amplify на бекэнде?
Такое дело, сейчас мы используем Apollo и на клиенте и на бекэнде, но бэк планирует перейти на AWS AppSync.
У AWS есть AWS Amplify который работает с GraphQL, но насколько я понял, что на клиенте можно дальше оставаться на Apollo и нет необходимости переходить на AWS Amplify, и можно дальше использовать Apollo для работы с GraphQL, но вопрос если есть какие ограничения при таком подходе или все работает без проблем?
